# Call function javascript from helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developed an application in ASP.NEt MVC4 with razor for safety reasons define a library (dll) a helper to go charging our GUI components (javascript / jquery) within this dll.

in the view code index.cshtml call follows the helper (Html.ToolBarControl ("Person")):

```
@using CrdToolBar;
@model MvcCrdToolBar.Models.Persona
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Registro de Persona</h2>
@using (Html.ToolBarControl("Persona")) { }
```

When view the page code, the javascript function I call this the top, before   need this function to create or add after the  any idea how do this?

Comment: So you want to know how to include JavaScript on the page when a call to `Html.ToolBarControl()` is made? I'm not sure I fully understand the question...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need to initialise some JS function/object *before* you call the Html.ToolbarControl helper? Couple of ways this can be done:

If you just want to have the JS inline then you can pretty much introduce it before you call it e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // JS here

</script>
@using (Html.ToolBarControl("Persona")) { }
```

If you have a master layout, introduce a new section for the head which will allow you to inject JS directly from your index.cshtml page (by default MVC already does this for you)

**Layer.cshtml**

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("Head", false);
</head>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using CrdToolBar;
@model MvcCrdToolBar.Models.Persona
@section Head {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // JS here
    </script>
}
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Registro de Persona</h2>
@using (Html.ToolBarControl("Persona")) { }
```